# Can you be "killed" but not yet dead

Tags: word-usage

I saw a western where one of the characters had been shot multiple times, miles from help and was clearly dying. He was speaking to the shooter and said something like "You've killed me".

Is it correct English to say this?

i.e. Do you have to be actually dead to have been "killed", or is dying enough.

Comment: I am not sure how this is at all an English question. You can say this in nigh every language. And the meaning is clear. Also, once you're dead you can't say anything at all anymore.

Comment: Interesting question. Can the victim grammatically say 'You've killed me'  shortly before he expires. If not, someone should correct him before he succumbs.

Comment: This is not directly connected to the verb 'kill'.  It is a less formal example of the 'prophetic perfect' usage. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophetic_perfect_tense). It has been covered before on ELU.